# How to extract a specific year from a column of timestamps in a csv file

Tags: regex, csv, awk, command-line

I have a large CSV file with many columns, and multiple columns that have timestamps. I want to filter the data for a specific year based on only 1 of those columns.

Example of what some of my input CSV looks like: (there are no headers)

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17263847 | 11/20/2018 3:00:13 PM | 11/23/2018 6:45:00 AM | Approved |
| 19483742 | 12/22/2019 4:00:12 PM | 1/10/2020 4:50:11 AM | Approved |
| 38274938 | 10/10/2018 2:02:19 PM | 02/07/2019 1:04:15 PM | Approved |

I want to extract all the rows that have 2019 in the second column; so for the example here, I would want to extract the 2nd row but not the 3rd row. Then, I want all of those rows to be put into a new CSV file.

Is there a simple way to do this using grep in command line? I used this but it's not working:

`awk -F, '$1=="2019"' file1.csv > file2.csv`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, in awk the second column is not `$1`, but `$2` (remember that `$0` refers to the whole line/register.
- Second: Instead of the `==` literal comparison, use the regex matching `~` (first [tutorial](https://opensource.com/article/19/11/how-regular-expressions-awk) I found).

The command you need is:

```sh
awk -F, -e '$2 ~ /2019/' file1.csv > file2.csv
```